# Returning Functions in Pythons

Tags: python, function

```
kk = ['kj','jk',5200,49]

def test_func1(kj):
    for i in kj: 
        value= i
        return value

def mainn_func(kk):
    v = test_func1(kk)
    print(v)
```

In the above function my print(v) statement does not print any thing , what are the possible changes that I can make , is there any problem with the return statement ?

Comment: Did you try calling it? `mainn_func(kk)`

Comment: I called it now and it works, fine, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling any functions.

At the bottom of your script, you will need to do `mainn_func(kk)`

Answer (score 0):

If u call the function mainn_func(kk) you will get only the first value of the list, because you return the value in first looping itself.

If u want to print each value of the list. Try this:

```
kk = ['kj','jk',5200,49]

def test_func1(kj):
    for i in kj: 
        value= i
        print value

test_func1(kk)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is very simple and returning only first value.

```
kk = ['kj','jk',5200,49]

def test_func1(kj):
    for i in kj: 
        value= i
        return value

def mainn_func(kk):
    v = test_func1(kk)
    print(v)
```

The problem looks like you are not calling this function call this like:-

```
mainn_func(kk)
```

## If you want to print only First value then use, don't write so much code, just write:-

```
print kk[1]
```

## If you want to print all values then write:-

```
def test_func1(kj):
    for i in kj:
        print i

def mainn_func(kk):
     test_func1(kk)

mainn_func(kk)
```

It will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is why, in some ways, Python is called a scripting language.  It simply runs through what is in the program as if it were typed into the command line interpreter.

This is hard to get used to if you come from languages like C.  In those languages, a function main(argc, argv) is the entry point of code.  You also need to forward-declare functions.  So, in C, you see patterns like:

```
float square(float);   /* C forward declaration so the compiler is happy*/

main(argc, argv) {
    int argc; char**argv;

    float z = 2;
    q = square(w);
    printf("%d", q);

}

float square (a) {
    float a;

    return a*a;
}
```

Python needs no main().  If you just give it a 'script' it just runs through it and does what you say.

So, a Python script that says:

```
def square(a) :
    return a*a

def main() :
    z = 2
    q = square(z)
    print q
```

does absolutely nothing other than define functions.  Either of these, however, would work:

Option 1: just say what you want:

```
def square(a) :
    return a*a

z = 2
q = square(z)
print q
```

In that case, it defines 'square', then (after that) sets z = 2; calls square; and then prints the result.

Option 2 is to make the single command, if you will, in the script, 'call main  to get things going':

```
def square(a) :
    return a*a

def main() :
    z = 2
    q = square(z)
    print q

main()
```

That approach (1) defines two functions, and (2) calls one of them (that being main) that then gets the ball rolling.

A Python program need not have a main.  But, check out the use of this idiom:

```
if (__name__ == '__main__').....
```

which is useful for putting test code in each file.

Comment: Thanks Sir , being new to python this was the most helpful post.